# Django deployment tool

Tags: django, django-deployment

I am looking for ready made deployment tool for django. Looking for tools like following which uses config files value to make deployment.

1. Meteor-up for deployment of meteor.js project.
2. python-lambda for department of python code to AWS lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created `dockdj` python tool, given that I didn't find the deployment tool like `Meteor-up` for Django.

Please find the link to the `dockdj` here: https://github.com/pavanputhra/dockdj